# What is the easiest way to get a hex color code from a set of color percentages in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, colors, hex, uicolor

What is the best way to get a hex color code from a set of three RGB percentages? For example:

```
[self getHexFromRed:0.5 Green:0.5 Blue:0.5]; // returns @"7F7F7F"
```

I've found several functions for going the other way (creating a color from a hex code), but I can't seem to find any easy way to do this...

Thanks for any help,
Chris

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2007/qa1576.html

Comment: @Bavarious Does this apply to iOS also?

Comment: @raidfive I’m not sure about iOS but the same principle (normalising up to 255.99999f) should apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write it from scratch:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X", 255 * redAsFloat,
                                            255 * greenAsFloat,
                                            255 * blueAsFloat];
```